# Open Flash Chart 2 not showing in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, ruby-on-rails-plugins, open-flash-chart

My question is about my first Open Flash Chart not displaying at all in my Rails application (2.3.5 running on Vista). I am trying to implement: http://openflashchart2.heroku.com/chart_examples/pie. All the code is in but when I load the view using the server, there's nothing there! Pull up the blank page's source code and I see:

```
    swfobject.embedSWF(
    "/open-flash-chart.swf","flashcontent_4000",
    "650", "300", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf",
    {"data-file":"/charts_ofc2%2Fpie"}, {{}}, {{}} );
```

but I do NOT see anything like this (this is copied from the source code of the example page):

```
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent"
    data="/open-flash-chart.swf" width="650" height="400"
    id="flashcontent_108400" style="visibility: visible; ">
    <param name="flashvars" value="data-file=http%3A%2F%2Fopenflashchart2.heroku.com%2Fcharts_ofc2%2Fpie"></object>
```

I think the lack of this chunk is why I'm not seeing the graph. Do you know where the problem is? Thank you so much.

*Background*

- Setup: RoR 2.3.5 running on a Windows
  machine, existing database and
  project under development.
- In vendor/plugins, I typed: git clone
  git://github.com/korin/open_flash_chart_2_plugin.git
  open_flash_chart_2
- Did rake open_flash_chart_2:install
- open-flash-chart.swf (265kb) is in public/
- swfobject.js is in public/javascripts
- json2 is in public/javascripts/json
- Also did the git clone and tried to do submodule
  update but it said: fatal: not a git
  repository (or any of the parent
  directories).
- Copied controller/view code into new controller
- I also named charts_ofc2 for pie chart
- Haml and JQuery are installed

Comment: check you have flash install in your pc?I have implemented Open Flash Chart in my application successfully.

Comment: Hi Salil, I do have flash installed on the pc. Does anything about the missing code I mentioned suggest where I'm going wrong?